# iOS 8 web app screen shrinks after loading camera app

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, web, camera

I am in the process a building a web app and ran into a problem with iOS 8. Please note this is specific to iOS 8 as it works fine in previous versions.

I have a page that uploads images taken directly from the phone or tablet. I use the following link to call the camera app:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="files[]">
```

The camera app opens as expected and takes the picture with no problem. However when the camera app closes and returns to the web app the screen height is reduced by more then half. There is no way to correct expect for closing and restarting the app.

You can see how it looks after taking the picture here:
[Screencast](http://screencast.com/t/ojbYUICAl1v)

It appears as if the screen remains in landscape. However rotating the device only makes it worse.

I am assuming this is an iOS 8 bug but wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to correct or work around the issue.

One last note, the issue only occurs when running as a web app. When using safari it works.

FYI - here are the meta tags I am using:

```
        <!-- Run in full-screen mode. -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

        <!-- Make the status bar black with white text. -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <!-- Customize home screen title. -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="DigiSite">

        <!-- Disable phone number detection. -->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

        <!-- Set viewport. -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <!-- Startup images -->

        <!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPad (retina, portrait) -->
        <link href="http://img.digisite.us/splash.png?w=1536&h=2008&c=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: background in <b>/home5/digisite/public_html/mobile/mobileHeader.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
&n=lumentum"
        media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
        and (orientation: portrait)
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
        rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

        <!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPad (retina, landscape) -->
        <link href="http://img.digisite.us/splash.png?w=1496&h=2048&c=&n=lumentum"
        media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
        and (orientation: landscape)
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
        rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

        <!-- iOS 6 iPad (portrait) -->
        <link href="http://img.digisite.us/splash.png?w=768&h=1004&c=&n=lumentum"
        media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
        and (orientation: portrait)
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
        rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

        <!-- iOS 6 iPad (landscape) -->
        <link href="http://img.digisite.us/splash.png?w=748&h=1024&c=&n=lumentum"
        media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
        and (orientation: landscape)
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
        rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

        <!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPhone 5 -->
        <link href="http://img.digisite.us/splash.png?w=640&h=1096&c=&n=lumentum"
        media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
        rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

        <!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPhone (retina) -->
        <link href="http://img.digisite.us/splash.png?w=640&h=920&c=&n=lumentum"
        media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
        rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Opened an issue on apple bug reporter. Problem ID: 19599472

Comment: I have seen this issue as well on ios8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issue on iPad 2 running iOS8. It seems to have to do with the orientation you open your app in. If we open the app in portrait(vertical) mode then switch to landscape(horizontal)  it works fine. It's only when the app is opened in landscape does the viewport shrink.

I haven't been able to reproduce this issue on iOS7.

Before photo capture:
[image: iPad before photo capture]

After photo capture:
[image: iPad after photo capture]

Comment: Interesting, do you know if there is a way to refresh the viewport when this occur?. There is really no way to prevent the user form starting the camera app in a specific orientation.

Comment: Not sure David. I'm trying to force a reload of the viewport with no luck. I submitted a bug to apple #18444627 if you have an apple dev account I think you can view it at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks Ben!!! Here is the steps to manually correct when using a web app. I hope this helps someone. [ScreenCast of Manual Fix](http://screencast.com/t/1mwIur5Z8)

Answer (score 1):

Ben, you are absolutely correct this is an iOS 8 bug. I can not determine how to programmatically work around it. If anyone else has any ideas please feel free to share. But there is a way to manually correct.

The problem seems to stem around the camera app not correctly identifying the correct position. On my iPhone, the camera app always opens in portrait mode even if held in landscape position. If you detect this, simply keep rotating the device until it auto corrects the position. It took two tries for me before it corrected itself. Once in the right mode, click on "Use Photo" and everything is fine. So as Ben said, as long as the the web-app and camera app are in the same orientation then all is fine. If they are not your web app view-port will be messed up. Once this occurs, your only recourse is to close the app and try again. One other interesting node, it only happens when running a full-screen app. If run through safari like any normal website there is no problem.

I documented the steps here to make sure what I said above is clear.
http://screencast.com/t/1mwIur5Z8.

I hope this helps out others. Hopefully, Apple will correct this.

Thank you Ben for submitting the defect to Apple!

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I opened a bugreport in the Apple bugtracker on Aug-6 but no one cares :-/ 
It seems to have something to do with

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

If you don't use this tag you have an overlapping status bar, but taking pictures doesn't resize your viewport anymore.
**Edit:**
Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
  </head>
  <body><h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Capture a photo using camera</p>
      <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried removing this meta tag but I personally did not see any changes. Looks like iOS 8 is worse then in previous versions. Thanks for your comment maybe it will help someone. Also thanks for opening another bugreport. Maybe if enough people raise this issue it will get resolved.

Comment: If you added your page to your home screen, you may need to re-add it after your code changes. I added some more code code to my answer. It worked on an iPad 3 with iOS 8.0.2 without resizing the screen after taking the photo

Answer (score 0):

Apple fixed this bug in iOS 8.3 beta 1